# Grails 2.3.x upgrade yielding repeat hasMany relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My Grails project is experiencing some strange behavior after upgrading from 2.2.x to 2.3.x. I have three simple domain types that are used for typical CMS functionality:  Post, Category, Tag such that a Post has many Category and Tag.

```
static hasMany = [categories: Category, tags: Tag]
```

When creating a Post, the user selects applicable Categories from a g:select ...multiple="multiple". Each category just shows once in the multiselect.  But now queries asking for Posts in a certain category are returning multiple entries of the same Post. Checking the MySQL database join table "post_category" created by Grails, I can see, there are indeed multiple entries:

```
Post_categories_id | category_id 
-------------------|------------
30000              | 1
30000              | 1
30000              | 2
30000              | 2
```

Has anyone seen a similar behavior? Recommendations for a fix? Right now I am just manually cleaning up the duplicates via SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had similar behavior when doing an upgrade.  But, I honestly can't remember what the hasMany relationships looked like.  A couple of questions/considerations:

- Are your hasMany relationships still a Set?  Did you implement hashCode() and equals() for the domain types of the hasMany relationships?  IIRC, this should enforce uniqueness.  One thing to consider, this unique constraint will fail upon creation now if it can not be enforced on the current dataset.  With that said, you can clean up the current data set with a SQL query.
- It looks like if you grouped those based on column1 and column2, you would get the data set you are looking for.  You could always retrieve records that way.  A bit dirty, and not ideal, but it will get you operational until getting down to the root solution.

I'll keep looking around.  If you post the domain for Post, Category and Tag it could help. Only the meat of it that matters (constraints, static hasMany map and the properties themselves) is necessary.

Additionally, you could turn on verbose logging and view the SQL statements that are running when you create a new post. My guess is it is happening here.  Snippets of your flow from the view where posts are created to the post.save() call would potentially be helpful too.

Comment: Implementing equals() and hashCode() did enforce uniqueness, thanks! I'm left with a strange behavior still such that Categories are not removed when they are deselected on the UI. For anyone facing the issue, I have temporarily put in a "postInstace.categories.clear()" before I rebuild the object from params. That works but still does not feel correct.